# Facebook graph API giving error - Unsupported get request with type - GraphMethodException

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using application access token with following API to download json -

https://graph.facebook.com/PageId?access_token=xxxxx&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json

I have two Facebook pages added on my Facebook account. so , for first page - I have passed correct Facebook Page Id & its Application access Token then it is is providing response properly

ex : - "Likes" : "xxx", "talking_about_count": xx.

But, when i try this API with my other Facebook page (with second page's - page id & its separately generated Application Access Token ) then it is giving error response -

```
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}.
```

If I use same PageId & Application AccessToken of second page with following API then it is working fine & giving proper response -

PageID/insights/page_views/day?

Any one can help me on this what is the issue with second page with API : -
PageId?access_token=xxxxx&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json

As the same Ids are working with Insights Page views API call then what is the issue/error with above API call ?